# How to set new line in caption and/or desription of facebook wall post in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have used Graph API and want to set "caption" and "description" in wall post.
Now problem is i have 2 parts in description which i want to set in 2 new separate lines but i can not set by using "\n" as it does nothing..
How to set new line in description or even in caption?

Below is my code.

```
- (void)uploadPhoto:(id)sender {

NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:6];

[variables setObject:@"My Messsage" forKey:@"message"];

[variables setObject:@"www.imagelink.com" forKey:@"picture"];

[variables setObject:@"www.google.com" forKey:@"link"];

[variables setObject:@"My Application name" forKey:@"name"];

[variables setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@:",@"www.google.com",@"My Word"] forKey:@"caption"];

[variables setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"My Description"] forKey:@"description"];


[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                       andParams:variables
                   andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                     andDelegate:self];

}
```

what i want is in above caption i have to different string printed in new lines..

Comment: What are they "caption" and "description" ? Are they NSString ?

Comment: yes they are string only

Comment: Since my initial guess was wrong, I can't add much without looking at the code. Could you post some snippets?